# css working on some pages, but not others

Tags: css

Somewhere along the way something went wonky with the CSS on this site.  One some posts, the side bar is in the correct position to the right: http://emgraphics.net/legacyjar/category/the-civil-rights-movement/.  But on the Pages and other Posts, it has scooted below the #wrapper area (http://emgraphics.net/legacyjar/). I had only made changes to the #comments section css but I don't see anything there that could have affected it.  Have fooled around with all the elements' widths, clear settings, etc. and just cannot nail this down.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It looks like your HTML is invalid - the structure is wrong: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Femgraphics.net%2Flegacyjar%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0 . On the faulty page, `#primary` is not inside `#main` like on the good page. Use a DOM inspector to see that  (`F12` on most browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

- You're making your CSS work harder than it has to.  You're setting container to 100% width then trying to use negative margin to give the sidebar room.  Instead, give the main container a set width.  Your site isn't fluid, so make life easier for yourself!

Here's the relevant CSS:

```
#container {
  float: left;
  width: 720px;
}
```

- You're prematurely closing one of your divs.  You have one too many close divs somewhere in the page that has the sidebar pushed down.  If you're in FF or Chrome, hit F12 and investigate the sidebar nav.  You'll see the div isn't in #main on the bad page, but it is on the good page.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the CSS, it's the HTML layout.

```
<div id="primary" class="widget-area" role="complementary"></div>
```

is supposed to be enclosed within

```
<div id="main"></div>
```

like so...

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="primary" class="widget-area" role="complementary"></div>
</div>
```

but on http://emgraphics.net/legacyjar/, 
your  primary div is outside of the main div like this...

```
<div id="main"></div>
<div id="primary" class="widget-area" role="complementary"></div>
```

Once you move the primary div back inside the main div, everything should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ahha! This would all make sense if it was a standard html site.  But I'm using a generic twenty-ten template for WordPress with css that I've edited.  All the pages have the same index/head/sidebar php files. However, there was an extra div tag on the comments.php file.  So pages where comments were not allowed worked. But pages/posts where they are allowed went wonky, EVEN if there were no comments OR even a comment form visible.  Thanks for the tip-off on the extra div tag!